# Fusion boosted fission reactor

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion, nuclear-engineering

With weapons, [fusion boosted fission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boosted_fission_weapon) seems to already be a thing. But I'm not interested in weapons.

Are there any types of fission reactor (other than a nuclear explosive) that would make more efficient use of fissile material by mixing in fusionable material?

Obviously the *average* temperature of a fission reactor isn't high enough for fusion, but the fission products will be in the right energy range for a couple of collisions while they are in the process of cooling down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something very close to this is the fusion-fission hybrid idea where fusion does not have to be at the point of self-sustaining burning (so it is below the ignition threshold) but rather driven by an external power source. Still, such a driven fusion reactor can produce lots of neutrons that can be used for driving fission burn of surrounding fissionable material. For example this could be used to extract energy from (and dispose of) nuclear waste that is not rich enough to go into self-sustaining fission reaction but with external neutron radiation one can drive fission reaction in it. Here is the Wikipedia article with detailed explanations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fusion-fission_hybrid

Comment: I hadn't thought of it that way around, but that definitely answers the question I ought to have asked. Thank you!